# Installing chisel

Tags: scala, chisel, riscv

I'm a new user of chisel. I tried to install chisel on my machine. According to the [git](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial), first I cloned chisel and then I went to hello directory and enter `make` . But I got the below error:

```
set -e -o pipefail; sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -DchiselVersion="latest.release" "run Hello --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd " | tee Hello.out
/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
make: *** [Hello.out] Error 2
```

I'm using sbt-0.13.8 and scala 2.11.6

Comment: What type of shell is "/bin/sh" pointing to? Does it work if it aliases to bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is from Shell variable the correct solution is that, adding following line to Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

It would solve the problem.

(They've updated the code)

Answer (score 3):

If you try without the command set -e -o pipefail it should works :

```
sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -DchiselVersion="latest.release" "run Hello --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd " | tee Hello.out
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked.
Just to make it clear, this line should be changed in root folder in `suffix.mk`