# Chisel installation error

Tags: bash, scala, sbt, chisel

While following [the tutorial on the Chisel official website for installation](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/latest/getting-started.html), I came to the point where I should test if the installation was done correctly. Doing so yields this error:

```
set -e -o pipefail; "sbt" -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -DchiselVersion="2.+" "run Parity --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd --targetDir /home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples " | tee /home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples/Parity.out
/bin/bash: sbt: command not found
make: *** [/home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples/Parity.out] Error 127
```

There is another question regarding the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402583/installing-chisel), where the suggestion to add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the Makefile is made. That did not work for me. Another suggestion is to remove `set -e -o pipefail`: this suggestion actually works but is it OK to remove that option? what does it do?

Edit_1:

I have installed sbt and added its path to the PATH variable.

```
$ which sbt
/usr/bin/sbt
```

But still I am getting this error when running `make Parity.out`

```
set -e -o  pipefail; "sbt" -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -DchiselVersion="2.+" "run Parity --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd --targetDir /home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples " | tee /home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples/Parity.out
/bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
make: *** [/home/me/chisel-tutorial/generated/examples/Parity.out] Error 2
```

If I edit this part of the file suffix.mk:

```
$(objdir)/%.dot: %.scala
            set -e  -o pipefail; "$(SBT)" $(SBT_FLAGS) "run $(notdir $(basename $<)) --backend dot --targetDir $(objdir) $(CHISEL_FLAGS)"

$(objdir)/%.out: %.scala
            set -e -o  pipefail; "$(SBT)" $(SBT_FLAGS) "run $(notdir $(basename $<)) --genHarness --compile --test --backend c --vcd --targetDir $(objdir) $(CHISEL_FLAGS)" | tee $@
```

By deleting the -o option in the `set -e -o  pipefail` it works, I get the PASSED and [success] message after running `$ make Parity.out`. So what is going on?

Edit_2:

It is working fine now after I added the `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the Makefile, so it was first a problem of not having sbt as Nathaniel pointed out then editing the Makefile to include `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set -e -o pipefail` is a way of making sure that the execution of the bash script both works as expected and that if there is a failure, it halts immediately (rather than at some later stage). Removing it might work - but if there is a failure it might get swallowed and hide the fact it's broken.

But I think your problem lies here, making the other question a bit of a red herring:

> /bin/bash: sbt: command not found

Do you have `sbt` installed on your system? Run `which sbt` as the user that executes the script. For instance, on my system:

```
$ which sbt
/opt/local/bin/sbt
```

If you don't have it on your system, nothing will be returned by running `which`.

The script clearly needs access to `sbt` and is failing when it doesn't find it. If you do have it on your system, then there is a mismatch between the user running the script and access to that file. You'll need to post more information about how you're executing the script: in that case it is likely you'll have to update your `PATH` variables to be able to find the `sbt` executable.

Given that, after fixing this, you still have a problem, you have to ensure that you're running in `bash`, and not another terminal type. The reason for this is that `bash` supports `set -o pipefail` but a lot of other terminals don't. We suspect this might be the case because of the error messages:

> /bin/sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail

Here we see that `/bin/sh` (the shell) is being invoked by the program. Use `ls -l /bin/sh` to determine if your `/bin/sh` is pointing to a particular shell. If it is not pointed to a `bash` shell, then you either need to repoint it (be careful! this is probably another question in it's own right), or need to specify to your Scala program to use a specific shell.

Comment: it is linking to dash: /bin/sh -> dash, when adding SHELL=/bin/bash to the Makefile it solves the problem. I think I will mark this as solved. If you have anything to add please do for future reference.